# Conditional ng-class style applies to all divs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a list of card numbers for a patient that displays on a modal. If the card is set to be the default card then it should have a grey background - this is based on a value of true for the object.

```
<td ng-repeat="obj in paymentAndShipping">
            <div ng-click="setDefaultPaymentMethod(obj.ElectronicPaymentAccountType, obj.ElectronicPaymentAccountID)" ng-class="{'chosencard' : obj.PreferredAccount }">
                <span ng-show="obj.PreferredAccount" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                <p>{{obj.ElectronicPaymentAccountType}} {{trimCardNum(obj.CreditCardNumber)}}</p>
                <p>Exp: {{obj.ExpirationDate}}</p>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Important piece:

```
ng-class="{'chosencard' : obj.PreferredAccount }"
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.chosencard {
        background-color: @gray-lighter;
    }
```

Here you can see that I iterate over the array and retrieve the objects using an ng-repeat and then apply an ng-class on the div inside the table cell to determine if the style is applied. The odd thing is that I do the same exact thing on the span inside the div and it reacts as I expect but the actual div doesn't - why is that?

Here's a screenshot of the behaviour.

P.S. When I click on an individual div the grey background disppears from all the others except the div that I clicked on. And of the four objects that you see above only one of them has a value of true and that's the last card.

[image]

Comment: what is the value obj.PreferredAccount?

Comment: @SantiagoRebella its a boolean

Comment: take in consideration you are checking if its falsey so includes `undefined` and `null` and `""`, and `0`, and `NaN`, and `false`). Try to narrow your comparisson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how you selecting payment methods but you can do that like in demo below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.paymentAndShipping = [

    {
      ElectronicPaymentAccountType: "a",
      CreditCardNumber: "155652",
      ExpirationDate: "01/01/2014",
      ElectronicPaymentAccountID: 1
    }, {
      ElectronicPaymentAccountType: "b",
      CreditCardNumber: "155652",
      ExpirationDate: "01/11/2014",
      ElectronicPaymentAccountID: 2
    }, {
      ElectronicPaymentAccountType: "c",
      CreditCardNumber: "1545652",
      ExpirationDate: "21/01/2414",
      ElectronicPaymentAccountID: 3
    }, {
      ElectronicPaymentAccountType: "d",
      CreditCardNumber: "1554652",
      ExpirationDate: "31/01/2024",
      ElectronicPaymentAccountID: 4
    }

  ];

  $scope.PreferredAccount = $scope.paymentAndShipping[0];

  $scope.setDefaultPaymentMethod = function(index) {

    $scope.PreferredAccount = $scope.paymentAndShipping[index];


  }

});
```

```css
.chosencard {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
td {
border:solid 1px grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="obj in paymentAndShipping">
          <div ng-click="setDefaultPaymentMethod($index)" ng-class="{'chosencard' :PreferredAccount==obj }">
            <span ng-show="obj.PreferredAccount" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <p>{{obj.ElectronicPaymentAccountType}} {{obj.CreditCardNumber}}</p>
            <p>Exp: {{obj.ExpirationDate}}</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<h3>PreferredAccount :</h3> {{PreferredAccount | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```